# Screen capturing in logon screen

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, winlogon, printscreen

I am trying to take a printscreen of Windows 7 Logon Screen (or Switch User screen) to use in my application.

I don't kow how to do that in fact. Could anyone help me?

Comment: I have searched on Google about that, but I found only ready-made tools...

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39197/Print-Screen-in-C and http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial181_Capturing-screenshots-using-Csharp.html

Comment: Will that work for Logon Screen?

Comment: Your app is a key-logger or a practical joke?

Comment: @rene: I don't think he making a keylogger, because screenshots on the logging is useless(password is hidden)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make a windows service so it can run even if the user isn't logged, take a look at this [article](http://myhosting.com/blog/2010/09/creating-windows-service-visual-studio-2010/) and for more information read the MSDN..

for the Screenshots:

```
ScreenCapture sc = new ScreenCapture();
// capture entire screen, and save it to a file
Image img = sc.CaptureScreen();
// display image in a Picture control named imageDisplay
this.imageDisplay.Image = img; 
// capture this window, and save it
sc.CaptureWindowToFile(this.Handle,"C:\\temp2.gif",ImageFormat.Gif);
```

source: http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4630/capture-a-screen-shot/

Comment: don't you have a C# source for that kind of service, because I don't know VB and this is the first time when I have to create a service...

Comment: @Victor If you cannot read VB.NET then simply compile the code to MSIL and have [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) display it as C#. Seriously, though, if you know C# then you should be able to read VB.NET without difficulty.

Comment: I read it, but I am not as good in VB as in C#. I do not often program in VB